# only in specified conditions the style work in less

Tags: less

In `less`, I have two class:

```
.business-type, .examine-type {
  height: 74px!important;

  ...  // there are many other styles
}
```

I have a requirement, only the class is `.examine-type`, I want the `height` work, how to realize this ?

Comment: You have to move the rule into a separate class definition. There's no way more simple than that.

Answer (score 0):

You can easy access it by doing this:

```
.examine-type {
  height: 74px!important;
}

.business-type, .examine-type {

  ...  // there are many other styles
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can separate out .examine-type class in different rule

```
.examine-type {
  height: 74px!important;
}
```

and inherit this class in .business-type if required,

```
.business-type{

  &:extend(.examine-type);

  ...  //  other styles

}
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the OP is asking for the opposite (`.business-type` should *not* have the `74px` height).